# how i can run xfreerdp +auth-only from php webserver?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, server

how i can run xfreerdp +auth-only from php webserver?
i want to run xfreerdp from php
code:

```
<?php $host = "52.25.33.205"; $user_name = "ben"; $password = "password"; set_time_limit(10); $r = ''; $result = shell_exec("timeout 10s xfreerdp /cert-ignore /v:". $host ." /port:3389 /u:". $user_name ." /p:'". $password ."' +auth-only 2>&1"); if (preg_match_all("/\bAuthentication only, exit status 0\b/",$result, $matches)): echo '1'; elseif(preg_match_all("/\bAuthentication only, exit status 1\b/",$result, $matches)): echo '0';
```

but when i run i get blank response,i try to run in php command i get same response (blank)
xfreerdp like block the command when i run from phpwebserver
please anyone can help me

i try to make RDP login checker from php